# Derivative of Zonal Polynomial w.r.t. Matrix Argument

Tags: matrices, special-functions, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

Let $\mathbf{T}$ be a real symmetric positive definite matrix. And let $\mathbf{Z}_\kappa\left(\mathbf{T}\right)$ denote the zonal polynomial as defined [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/35.4#E3).

Does
$$
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}_\kappa\left(\mathbf{T}\right)}{\partial \text{vech}(\mathbf{T})}
\end{equation}
$$
exist in closed form?

I couldn't find any results in the academic literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks for the derivative of $Z_\kappa(\mathbf{T})$ with respect to {\it every} entry $t_{i,j}$ of the $m \times m$ positive definite (symmetric) matrix $\mathbf{T}$.  This is generally an intractable problem even for small $m$ and partitions $\kappa$ of low weight.  For instance, suppose $m=3$ and $\kappa = (2,2,1)$, the use of {\sl Mathematica} to calculate $\partial Z_\kappa(\mathbf{T})/\partial t_{1,1}$, the derivative with respect to $t_{1,1}$, leads to results that are impenetrable, i.e., do not seem to have any structure.

So this raises the issue of whether the problem that motivates your question really require all such derivatives.  Perhaps you may wish to elaborate on the motivating problem.

Noting that the zonal polynomials $Z_\kappa(\mathbf{T})$ are othogonally invariant functions of $\mathbf{T}$, and therefore depend only on the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{T}$, perhaps you only need the derivatives of $Z_\kappa(\mathbf{T})$ with respect to the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{T}$.  If this is the case then see the book, `Aspects of Multivariate Statistical Theory'' (Wiley, New York, 1982), or the paper,` Applications of invariant differential operators to multivariate distribution theory,'' SIAM J. Appl. Math., 45 (1985), 280--288.

Or perhaps you only need to calculate $\phi(\partial/\partial\mathbf{T}) Z_\kappa(\mathbf{T})$, where $\phi(\cdot)$ is an orthogonally invariant function of $\mathbf{T}$.  In that case, a generating-function approach to evaluating such derivatives is given in two papers, `Differential operators associated with zonal polynomials. I,'' Ann. Inst. Statist. Math. 34 (1982), 111-–117, and` Differential operators associated with zonal polynomials. II'' Ann. Inst. Statist. Math. 34 (1982), 119--121.